# Convert a number of day into a date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, date-arithmetic, date-conversion

Is it possible to convert a day of the year number to a date?

For example, in oracle I can get the day of the year number by:

```
Select to_char(sysdate,'ddd') as "y_num_day" from dual;
```

I would need the reverse to perform some date arithmetic.

Comment: Assuming you have the `year`, yes -- `date_add` comes to mind...

Comment: Add N-1 days to the first day of the year: `SELECT TO_DATE('20160101','YYYYMMDD') + N - 1 FROM dual`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert it back to a date, use `to_date`

```
select to_date(to_char(sysdate,'ddd'),'ddd') as "date" from dual
```

[List of valid parameters for to_date](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed.
I translated to
select to_date(202,'ddd') as "date" from dual;
and gave me the expected date in format.

Answer (score 0):

you also can plus it back to year start date, like this

```
with a as ( Select to_char(sysdate,'ddd') y_num_day from dual )

select trunc(sysdate,'year') + to_number(a.y_num_day) - 1 from a
```